# Select columns containing string

Tags: sql, select, contains

Is it possible to retrieve all data in columns containing a particular string? I do not have any control over the data structure and I rather shorten my code than to type everything if possible. As far as I know statements as `LIKE` and `CONTAIN` are only used to retrieve particular rows instead of columns. Lets say I have a table with column names: time, run1, run2, run3, ....., run 34, I would like to use something like:

```
SELECT columns FROM [Tablename] WHERE columns CONTAIN 'run';
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have to search 30 something columns for a string that might be a pretty heavy query.. are you only wanting the column names returned or the values in the columns?

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL.  This functionality is not natively part of SQL.

Comment: What is `SELECT columns` supposed to do? With SQL SELECT you specify which columns from a table you want to see and in WHERE you specify which rows you want to see. What is your result supposed to look like? How many rows? How many columns? Can you give an example of a result you'd like to see?

Comment: please tag the database you are using

Comment: I think you are going to much happier just typing the column names.  Any other solution is much harder.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wanted to retrieve the values within the columns not the column names.

Answer (score 2):

Use `like`.

In Oracle, you could do

```
SELECT column_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
and lower(column_name) like 'run%'
```

In SQL Server, you could do

```
SELECT column_name 
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
and lower(column_name) like 'run%'
```